# Second Chern class of a smooth projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ such that $-K_X$ is ample. If $h^0(-K_X) >0$, then the first Chern class of $X$ can be seen as a cycle of co-dimension $1$ associated to a section of $-K_X$. The second Chern class can be represented by a cycle of co-dimension $2$.

Qestion: Is there any way to identify a cycle associated to  the second Chern class of $X$ ?

Comment: Is it not just the zero locus of a general section $\sigma \in H^0(X, \, \Omega^1_X)$?

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: Since $-K_X$ is ample, $H^0(X,\Omega ^1_X)$ is zero.

Comment: I do not know. Could you please give some reference or some hind to show it ?

Comment: If $T_X$ is globally generated,  pick $n-1$ general sections $s_1,\ldots ,s_{n-1}$ of $H^0(X,T_X)$; then $c_2$ is represented by $\{x\,|\,s_1(x),\ldots ,s_{n-1}(x)$ linearly dependent$\}$.

Comment: @LAPRAS: In case you are asking why $H^0(X,\Omega ^1_X)=0$, this is by Hodge symmetry + Kodaira vanishing.

Comment: If $T_X$ is not globally generated  then can we say something ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I guess if $T_X$ is not nef then most of the cases it will not be globally generated.

Comment: @abx: ah, right, thanks. I misread "$K_X$ is ample".

Comment: @LAPRAS: Are you asking if $c_2$ is effective, or do you want any its cycle representation (allowing some negative coefficients)?

Comment: I am asking when $c_2$ is effective.